# Esri API JS, popup not displaying after first click

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

Demographics data shows upon first click but not after, park information does work. I've changed around almost everything with non real solution. I feel like for whatever reason my feature server data is preferred over the dynamiclayer in the map. Is there a way to make the js bounce based on where you click?

```
    var map;

    require([
      "esri/config",
      "esri/InfoTemplate",
      "esri/map",
      "esri/dijit/Popup",
      "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
      "esri/geometry/Extent",
      "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
      "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
      "esri/tasks/query",
      "dojo/dom-construct",
      "dojo/dom-class",
      "dojo/parser",
      "esri/Color",
      "dojo/_base/lang",
      "dojo/date/locale",
      "esri/dijit/Geocoder",
      "esri/dijit/LocateButton",      
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
      function (
        esriConfig, InfoTemplate, Map, Popup, PopupTemplate, Extent, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer, 
        ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        GeometryService, Query, domConstruct, domClass, parser, Color, lang, locale, Geocoder, LocateButton 
      ) {

        parser.parse();


        var popup = new Popup({
          fillSymbol: new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
              new Color([0, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([128, 128, 128, 0.25]))
        }, domConstruct.create("div"));

        domClass.add(popup.domNode, "myTheme");

        map = new Map("map", { 
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-122.402, 47],
          zoom: 9,
          infoWindow: popup          
        });

        var geocoder = new Geocoder({
        arcgisGeocoder: {
          placeholder: "Search "
        },
        map: map
      }, "ui-esri-dijit-geocoder");

      var _countyCensusInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
      _countyCensusInfoTemplate.setTitle("<b>Census Information</b>");

      var _blockGroupInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
      _blockGroupInfoTemplate.setTitle("<b>Census Information</b>");

      var _censusInfoContent =
        "<div class=\"demographicInfoContent\">" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_5_17:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 5 - 17<br>" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_18_21:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 18 - 21<br>" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_22_29:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 22 - 29<br>" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_30_39:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 30 - 39<br>" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_40_49:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 40 - 49<br>" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_50_64:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 50 - 64<br>" +
        "<div class='demographicNumericPadding'>${AGE_65_UP:formatNumber}</div><div class=\"demographicInnerSpacing\"></div>people ages 65 and older" +
        "</div>";

      _countyCensusInfoTemplate.setContent("Demographics for:<br>${NAME} ${STATE_NAME:getCounty}, ${STATE_NAME}<br>" + _censusInfoContent);
      _blockGroupInfoTemplate.setContent("Demographics for:<br>Tract: ${TRACT:formatNumber} Blockgroup: ${BLKGRP}<br>" + _censusInfoContent);      

      var demographicsLayerURL = "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer";
      var demographicsLayerOptions = {
        "id": "demographicsLayer",
        "opacity": 0.8,
        "showAttribution": false
      };

      var demographicsLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(demographicsLayerURL, demographicsLayerOptions);
      demographicsLayer.setInfoTemplates({
        1: { infoTemplate: _blockGroupInfoTemplate },
        2: { infoTemplate: _countyCensusInfoTemplate }
      });
      demographicsLayer.setVisibleLayers([1, 2]);
      map.addLayer(demographicsLayer);

      geocoder.startup();

      var geoLocate = new LocateButton({
      map: map,
      highlightLocation: false
      }, "LocateButton"
      );
      geoLocate.startup();

    var formatNumber = function(value, key, data) {
      var searchText = "" + value;
      var formattedString = searchText.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/gm, "$1,");
      return formattedString;
    };

    var getCounty = function(value, key, data) {
      if (value.toUpperCase() !== "LOUISIANA") {
        return "County";
      } else {
        return "Parish";
      }
    };

        map.on("click", function (event) {
          var query = new Query();
          query.geometry = pointToExtent(map, event.mapPoint, 10);
          var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query,
            FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
          map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
          map.infoWindow.show(event.mapPoint);
        }); 

      var template = new InfoTemplate();
        template.setTitle("Park Information");
        template.setContent(getTextContent);

        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services3.arcgis.com/J1Locv0GPOt6yBRR/ArcGIS/rest/services/Parks_polygons_Feb2012/FeatureServer/0",
          {            
            outFields: ["*"],
            infoTemplate: template
          });

        map.addLayer(featureLayer);

        function getTextContent (graphic) {
          var attributes = graphic.attributes;
          var namepark =
            attributes.ParkName
            .replace('"', "")
            .split("::")
            .map(function (name) {
              return lang.trim(name);
            });

          var parkdata = namepark[0];
          var commonName = namepark[1];
          var parks;

          if (commonName) {
            parks = "<b>" + commonName + "</b><br/>" +
                          "<i>" + parkdata + "</i>";
          }
          else {
            parks = "<i>" + parkdata + "</i>";
          }

          return  parks + "<br>" +
                  attributes.Owner + "<br>" + 
                  attributes.ParkWebLin 
        }        

        function pointToExtent (map, point, toleranceInPixel) {
          var pixelWidth = map.extent.getWidth() / map.width;
          var toleranceInMapCoords = toleranceInPixel * pixelWidth;
          return new Extent(point.x - toleranceInMapCoords,
                            point.y - toleranceInMapCoords,
                            point.x + toleranceInMapCoords,
                            point.y + toleranceInMapCoords,
                            map.spatialReference);
        }    

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="map">
  <div id="LocateButton"></div>
</div>
<div id="ui-esri-dijit-geocoder"></div>

</body>
```

link to is http://students.washington.edu/sbuffor/combined_census_parks.html

Comment: Cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120616/esri-javascript-api-census-info-popup-and-parks-popup-one-map

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. For some ideas on how to structure a question to attract potential answerers I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: 2. Using htmlPrettify you will see that your code isn't able to format properly, that's how I found the extra closures in there. 3. Yes name the popups differently, but you cannot change the class name! ie "var popup1 = new Popup()" - where Popup() is the class name. You can differentiate the variable name (you must in fact) ie  "var parkPopup" vs "var blockPopup" but you must leave " = new Popup()" as is - that is the class.

Comment: Ok the map is rendering but the demographics info only comes up on the first click. I assume this relates to your comment "Make the div first with dojo attach point?" but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: This is my latest point of hangup...http://students.washington.edu/sbuffor/combined_census_parks.html I can't get the demographics info to show after the first click, if you click the parks first demographics doesn't come up at all.

Comment: Your code is quite complicated, and is probably _unnecessarily_ complicated. A suggestion is to take the simple [feature layer sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_ondemand.html) and get it working with your ArcGIS Server, then add functionality as required

Comment: I originally built two maps and wanted to put them together leading to this cluster. I'll take a look at your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I tried this example and it simply won't work. I can get the second layer on there but I can't get any information via a popup to display. I tried to use the same set-up to add the second layer infotemplate and no luck.

Comment: OK I'll take a look tomorrow. A suggestion in the meanwhile is to reduce this code to the absolute bare minimum required to reproduce the problem. Eg, the `geocoder`, `locateButton` and the `formatNumber` function are superfluous to the problem, so you could remove them to make things easier to debug. Once you get it working you can add things back sequentially to verify it still works afterwards

Comment: What browser are you using?  The parks are queried with every click I am making (tested in FireFox).  Also, just a suggestion for presentation of the popups, you may want to use a hyperlink for the park website rather than the plain text in your `getTextContent()`:  `'<a href="' + attributes.ParkWebLin + '">View Park Website</a>"'`

Comment: Chrome. I was wanting to get the map working correctly before addressing hyperlink, but that's a great suggestion.

Comment: Looking at this code, there is a lot of stuff going on and I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. I strongly suggest that you need to break this question down, and include the bare minimum code required to demonstrate the problem. I would start with a clean slate and add the minimum code required to demonstrate the problem, then stop. You're more likely to get assistance on this site if you can make it easier for us to quickly identify the single problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started removing pieces and found a piece that I didn't completely understand what it was doing and pulled it out.

```
map.on("click", function (event) {
          var query = new Query();
          query.geometry = pointToExtent(map, event.mapPoint, 10);
          var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query,
            FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
          map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
          map.infoWindow.show(event.mapPoint);
        });
```

Upon doing this the map now is completely operational!

Also I took the advice to add the URL to the park info, got that added in as well, although I did remove the "getTextContent" piece out of it to get it to render properly but it works quite well. I also added another piece to open the link in a new tab.